# Why are two forward and reverse priming sites depicted here? what do they do?

Tags: genetics, dna-sequencing, plasmids, primer, recombinant

This question is in regard to the baculovirus expression system.

[image]
<sub>(source: [amsbio.com](http://www.amsbio.com/images/pagelayout/BPE.jpg))</sub>

Why do we need to generate primers for the polyhedrin promoter and the baculovirus? 
Primers are needed to amplify DNA regions of interest.Here, why exactly do we need to amplify these regions? and at which steps?

PS : I am not asking about the need for forward and reverse primers.

[image: The DNA sequence, which shows forward and reverse priming sites for Polyhedrin promoter, and forward and reverse priming sites for baculovirus]

Comment: what is this slide and why does it have so many typos?

Answer (score 1):

It's just extra information that you don't need to understand the part above. You could use these primers for colony PCR or sequencing when you'd use the plasmid (after transforming to E.coli for example), but they're not absolutely required.

Compare it with [this map](http://www.addgene.org/vector-database/2565/) for example. There are also some primer sites listed, but you don't actually need those primers for anything.